cannot pass the authentication to view the data table in power bi
My URL is https://www.sourcingmachine.co.uk/user-profile/01001
Get Data from web config shows you need to login first. I added a 'Basic' with my credentials but still shows the same page as 'You need to login first.
I have a log-in and despite what I try, it hasn't worked.
When I go use Anonymous, i am just taken to the front page of this website where I "log in", but not past it.
